# combo box in datagrid in flash cs4 as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cs4

Can some one please direct me to a example where a combo box has been inserted in a datagrid using as3 in CS4. I have a idea that it can be done using the cellrenderer, but i am not able to figure out how to achieve it. i tried searching on net but could not find any working example.
I am working on a project where there are mutiple rows in the datagrid, and the values of the datagrid item can be changed using the combo box inside it.
I have just started on actionscript so not much experience on that part. I have been searching on net for quite few thing and working them out.
if some one can provide me a simple example of this, that would be gr8.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something similar to:

```
public function createChildren() : void
    {
        combo = createObject("ComboBox", "Combo", startDepth++);

        // Assign the data provider.
        combo.dataProvider = COMBOBOX_DATA_PROVIDER;


        combo.addEventListener(ComboBoxEvent.change, changeEvent);
        combo.addEventListener(ComboBoxEvent.open, openEvent);
    }
```

Comment: can you please give me a example of how to use this. i found a example for as2 here 
http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flash/fl8/samples.html
in my app there are 3 column which needs to be of the combox box.